# Strange function-signature: 'fun Date.getTimeAgo() ... ' - Meaning?

Tags: kotlin

Can someone explain this syntax?

```
fun Date.getTimeAgo(): String { /* ... */ }
```

What's this 'Date.' prefix? What's the benefit, respectively meaning? Why isn't the name of the function just 'getTimeAgo'?

Comment: This is an extension function. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html

Comment: @Javlon Thanks :) If you like: Turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.